# Using setId() to assign known Ids from variable

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I have a RelativeLayout, with four rows of three buttons. I have the IDs created in an XML file like so:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="row1" />
    <item type="id" name="button1" />
    <item type="id" name="button2" />
    <item type="id" name="button3" />
    <item type="id" name="row2" />
    <item type="id" name="button4" />
    <item type="id" name="button5" />
    ...
</resources>
```

And I can find which button was pressed with this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // do something
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // do something else
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            // i'm lazy, do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to assign the IDs to the buttons when they're being created in the loop. Ideally I'd like to use `setId(R.id.myKnownId)` in a loop, but I can't.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this, other than hard-coding it in after the buttons have been created?

Edit: Code added.

```
for ( int j = 1 ; j < 5 ; j ++ ) {
        int rowtemp = j;
        currentRow.setTag("row"+rowtemp);
        currentRow.setId(rowtemp); //<-- I want to add R.id.definedId here

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            int temp = buttonNumber;
            btn.setId(temp); //<-- same thing here
            btn.setTag("button"+buttonNumber);
            btn.setText(buttonNumber + "");
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            buttonNumber++;
        }
}
```

Comment: *"...I'd like to use setId(R.id.myKnownId) in a loop, but I can't. ..."* Why you can't? this is quite possible.

Comment: You can use `getIdentifier` inside your loop

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I'd like to use setID(R.id.variableUsedInALoop).

Pedro, how to I point GetIdentifier to ids.xml?

Comment: @Serephucus I can't figure out what do you mean, can you post a snippet code related to that *loop*?

Comment: There's no need to point to ids.xml. In the end all ids will be on R.java. Not on xml files.

Comment: So why can't you use `setId(R.id.someid)`? What error you've gotten?

Comment: you can set any integer as id.

Comment: The issue is that I need to differentiate the rows from the buttons, all of which need unique IDs.  In XML, I could set 'code'android:id="button1"'code' but via code, I can only pass positive ints.